# What is the name for a paginated scrolling effect with distinct stopping points in the scroll?

Tags: javascript, css

For example:

http://deppo.tkdemos.com/portfolio/grid-references-in-the-latest-issue/

What is the name of the scrolling effect used on the link above? Where when you scroll or arrow down the page scrolls and stops at a specific point. I'm trying to implement on a wordpress site but can't seem to search effectively for a solution without being able to name it.

Comment: I think this is just a vertical slider. So just a slider that just slides vertically instead of horizontal.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to "see" the effect you are describing... any other examples?